# SQL query (2 select together in a table)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have to combine two queries, but I don't how to do it.

First:

```
select  * 
from Kalender 
where Datum between #{startDate.ToShortDateString()}# and #{endDate.ToShortDateString()}#
```

Second is a `DELETE` query to remove all duplicates with the same name.

I know I should use `DISTINCT`, but I do not know exactly how to write this.

Comment: you can use `count()` with `having()`

Comment: http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-distinct/ read this page it explains the use of `DISTINCT` and should help you

Comment: I do not want to have a count of the data I need all the data except the one with the same name. It would be very nice of you if you write the sql query

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: yes in my program I import each time an xml file and will always save in a microsoft acsess but the problem is always the old date with the new dates are saved and I want that he always checks or the same name gives then he has do not save that

Comment: i post the code link pls i want a solution fast

Comment: It's not okay to link to the full solution. No one here as the time to go through all of it, and fewer still will trust a random google drive link. Cut out just the bare SQL excerpts you need and paste them directly into the question as formatted text. Based on what I did see, _you're not using MySql!_ You're using MS Access. Please be careful with your tag choices. Also, `QueryAsDataTable()` is forcing you write SQL that's crazy-vulnerable to sql injection bugs. This is a **big deal**. You need to refactor the method to accept query parameters in a different argument from the SQL command text

Answer (score 0):

this one will delete all rows that have duplicates (including "the original" one)

```
delete from
    Kalender
where
    Datum in (  select
                    Datum
                from
                    Kalender
                where
                    Datum between   #{startDate.ToShortDateString()}#
                                    and #{endDate.ToShortDateString()}#
                group by
                    Datum
                having
                    count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I do not want all rows the duplicates have to be deleted but only those who have the same name should be deleted

Comment: So you have column `name` in `Kalender`?

Comment: but I also want all the ones without duplicate name to be displayed like in my first sql query

Comment: if you don't want to delete any rows, but only display rows that have no duplicates in `name` column, try this query ```select
    k.*
from
    Kalender as k
    join (  select
                name
            from
                Kalender
            where
                Datum between   #{startDate.ToShortDateString()}#
                                and #{endDate.ToShortDateString()}#
            group by
                name
            having
                count(*) = 1) as x on k.name = x.name
```